# How to create torch.tensor with shape (1,1,32) with default value?

Tags: pytorch

I want to create `torch.tensor` variable with shape (1,1,32) with default value (`None`).

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can assign `None` to a `torch.Tensor`. What is more appropriate however is to instead assign `NaN`. You can do so using the builtin [`torch.full`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.full.html):

```
>>> torch.full((1, 1, 32), torch.nan)
tensor([[[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
          nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
          nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 
          nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]])
```